# light weight java web framework with jdk1.3

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, websphere

here is situation, my boss ask me to develop a web application for querying and editing data of tables in a database. Then server environment is restricted to jdk1.3 with websphere(a old version, i dont remember which) as application server. This web application need to be light weight as the server is old and slow. the database to be connected is not finalized and my boss proposed to use jdni for later switching database, i will be using oracle for testing. 
As the websphere is not yet setup in server, my boss ask me to test on jboss 3.2.7 first and later migrate to websphere when it is ready. 
Is there any framework that is light weight and compatible for jdk1.3, jboss and websphere that simplify the task like object relational model, mvc etc.

Comment: Restricted? Any particular reason for the restriction? That's not even in vintage support anymore!

Comment: I also question why an old version of WebSphere, that isn't even installed yet, is being used. If it's old enough to be not supported, you might as well use a lightweight but more modern unsupported solution. (Meaning, something free with only community support.)

Comment: What i mean is that the client's environment is fixed but the testing environment of my company is not yet setup

Answer (score 3):

Use straight forward JSP + Servlets + JDBC approach since you need every thing to be lightweight and JDK 1.3 compatible. Use Apache DBUtils to ease JDBC pains.

Comment: that would not take care of his ORM and MVC needs.

Comment: Depending on the number of tables involved, with the technology constraints (pre-historic JDK and App servers), Struts and/or hibernate would not be a feasible strategy. I would rather create simple master+detail jsp pages with complementing servlets utilizing a simplified JDBC API.

Answer (score 0):

Develop a new app on JDK 1.3 and an old version of WebSphere?  What's the rationale for this **poor** decision?

That JDK reached its EOL on 25-Oct-2004.  That's almost *seven years ago*!  That's pre-generics, pre-collections, pre-concurrency package, pre-generational garbage collection, and a host of other improvements.

You and your boss should reconsider this decision.  There's no reason that would explain it.  If it's cost, get a free Java app container.  If it's a web app, use Spring and deploy on Tomcat; if you require EJBs, use JBOSS.

Comment: i dont think the client's server environment is changeable by my boss